# Add line break after first paragraph in MySql with no specific match character

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have just over 1000 posts in WordPress which look a similar to this:

> A treasure trove of pop culture memorabilia helped Hake's Americana to a total of $1.1 million in its most recent collectibles sale.
> The sale was led by several rare Superman collectibles, most notably an original painting by renowned comic book artist Frank Frazetta. Dating from 1988, the artwork marked the only time in his long career that Frazetta ever depicted the Man of Steel, and sold for a suitably super $35,420.

I need to put a break after the first paragraph so that it is formatted like this:

> A treasure trove of pop culture memorabilia helped Hake's Americana to a total of $1.1 million in its most recent collectibles sale.
>
> The sale was led by several rare Superman collectibles, most notably an original painting by renowned comic book artist Frank Frazetta. Dating from 1988, the artwork marked the only time in his long career that Frazetta ever depicted the Man of Steel, and sold for a suitably super $35,420.

I'm looking to run an update statement on the database (MySQL) to match a character and replace it with relevant formatting.

I've tried looking for linebreaks and replacing them with two linebreaks with the following statement:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(post_content, 
INSTR(post_content, '+char(13)+')), '+char(13)+', '+char(13)+'), 
SUBSTRING(post_content, INSTR(post_content, '+char(13)+') + 1))
WHERE post_type = 'post';
```

There must be something there controlling the format of the data, but I've put the content in various editors and can't see any special characters which I could do a find and replace on.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If your MySQL server is running on some form of unix then the newline character will be char(10)

Comment: @nick unfortunately that didn't work. Although there could be something wrong with my SQL. It was originally wrong but I've updated my original post.